# How does companies make staff users?

Tags: django, email, backend, user-accounts

Apologies since this might not be the best way to word the question nor is this a coding question per say. I get the general process of creating a staff user within Django.

What I would like to know is if companies send email links that allow their workers to sign up a form to be a staff user or if the employer provides their details and someone on the backend creates this account for them, or some other process I am unaware of?

Comment: I think the answer would depend on the company, its size, and the maturity of its IT (and HR) processes.   And also on the technologies that they use; e.g. is there a corporate SSO mechanism?

Comment: I am extremely green so I appreciate this answer since it made me more aware of the different authentication types such as SSO or MFA after researching it more and real world factors that I wasn't thinking about. If you have websites/article recommendations to learn more about any of the 4 tags of this question that would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, most of the time they create you account with documents/personal info you've provided to the organization. In my university user accounts are created by staff(no need to fill forms and besides, you can fake that information). At the end, we just go to the website and login with provided credentials, we can add extra info/change password etc. in our account settings.

In conclusion, I would say, it depends.